# Does WSO APIM supports use of existing GraphQL to be published

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Need to know if WSO API Manager supports publishing existing GraphQL Endpoints like we do for REST API by selecting option called Have a Existing API?

I have graphql API's already published and need to route it via WSo APIM

Answer (score 0):

The next version of WSO2 API Manager which is v3.0.0 supports Graph QL APIs. When creating an API, you can give the GraphQL SDL schema file along with the endpoint. You can read about the feature in https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/3184

Comment: Thanks , I found the same thing when browsing to find about it!

Checking options to try it out before they roll in too .... :)